# Guidance implementing Google One tap sign-up and automatic sign-in

Tags: web, oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to implement Google's 
[One tap sign-up and automatic sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview).

I can successfully prompt the user for sign-on, get an ID token from Google, and validate it on the server. Where I am lost is what do I do with the ID token once I have it? [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/idtoken-auth#create-an-account-or-session) is vague.

I get the impression that I send something back to the browser to store in Session Storage, but what do I send and how I use it to verify that the user is authenticated on future requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're all the way up to "Create an account or session" in that Guide, you're pretty much done with the problem of integrating with Google Identity.

There is nothing to return to the browser from Google's perspective.  The client-side API has retrieved the token, you've sent it to your server, your server has used it to successfully verify and extract the user's Google account information, authentication is complete.

What happens next is your decision.  It depends what your website does with the user's details (e.g. create a user in your database, do stuff to remember them for the rest of their visit).

Google Identity is not authorisation, only authentication.  It provides identity ("who is this user?"), not permissions ("what is the user allowed to do?", "How long should I trust this session for?").  User permissions is a separate problem.

To remember a user for future requests, you would typically create a unique, one-time unpredictable session token on the server, and store that in a HTTP-only, secure session cookie.  As already explained, this is unrelated to Google Identity.